# regex to match everything until it finds 2 upper case characters?

Tags: php, regex

so far I have this

```
(?:(?![A-Z]{2,}).)*
```

which matches everything until HTTPHEADER, however I want it to stop when it sees HttpHeader

how to do that?

so if I have string like `Http is an HttpHeader`

it should match `Http is an`

Comment: Does that mean you want to step the match when it sees the same two upper case characters? And does that mean that the match in `HttpHeader` should be `HttpH`?

Comment: it should see HttpHeader and stop, edited

Comment: So, if the string is: `Http is a Nice Header`, it should match `Http is a Nice `? And if you have `Http is a Nice thiNg to Have`, should it match `Http is a Nice thi`?

Comment: @Jerry not it should match Http is a Nice thiNg to Have, it does not matter where the capital letter is just that there is no 2 capital letters in any word

Comment: Then I think the string in your question is wrong; it should be `Http is an HttpHeader`, right?

Comment: ah of course sorry!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use this:

```
^(?:(?!(?:\S*[A-Z]){2}).)+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/sE2yZ1)

`(?:\S*[A-Z]){2}` will match only if a word has two uppercase characters.

And since this is in a negative lookahead, the match will stop only if a word with two uppercase characters is found ahead.

Comment: It might actually be a bit faster if you use `[^\sA-Z]*` instead of `\S*` there.

Answer (score 0):

using Jerry's suggestion and this pattern is much more efficient
`^.*(?=\b(?:[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z]){2})` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kB5eO9)

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?(?=[A-Z]\S*[A-Z]))
```

Why should we make it hard?! [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/zJ6jJ7)