# regex to match everything until it hits uppercase

Tags: php, regex

I found the following code from this question, [regex to match everything until it finds 2 upper case characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717932/regex-to-match-everything-until-it-finds-2-upper-case-characters)

```
^.*(?=\b(?:[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z]){2})
```

however my question is slightly different then the OP

I want to match everything up to the upper case in the following string,
the rules should match everything until it negative lookaround finds 2 uppercase characters and then match everything inbetween from the 1st uppercase until the start of the 2nd uppercase character

so I Want (continue from op example)

```
Http is an HttpHeader
```

is to get `Http is an Http`

instead of `Http is an` which OP is getting in posted thread

Comment: Can you clarify your rules?  Your example doesn't match your description as matching everything until uppercase would return nothing as the first uppercase is the first character

Comment: Agree with @psubsee2003 -- the result you want contains *two* upper cased characters!

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx to split camelCase or TitleCase (advanced)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593969/regex-to-split-camelcase-or-titlecase-advanced)

Comment: @mvp does not actually work as expected see http://regex101.com/r/bO7aP8

Comment: Use `(?<! )(?=[A-Z])`

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly comp. to me

```
preg_match( '/[^A-Z]+/', $str, $res );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/[^A-Z]*([A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{1}[^A-Z]*)/', $str, $res);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern `^.*?(?=\b(?:[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z]){2}).+?(?=[A-Z])` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fO4nD5)

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-Z].*?\w+(?=[A-Z]))
```

You may follow the above regex. That's so simple and yet fast. See matched groups here: [Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/fN1fI1)